Query records with certain picklist values in Salesforce flow
I need my screen flow to do the following:
Get Contacts with values A, B and C in a multipicklist field_A. I just need to checkif that values are selected, but there can be different contacts (Contact A with A and B in field A and Contact B with value C). Any combination is possible, just need to have related contacts that are of that type.
As it is a multipicklist field I have first used a Get Records to obtain all the contacts filteredas much as possible and later I need to use a collection filter to filter by the multipicklist.
How can I check that contact(s) exist with that values?
Edit
Firt I tried to query for each of the values on the multipicklist field with a get records element but it is returning an error as it s a multipicklist.
If this case worked it would be really useful because it doesn't matter if each box finds the same record, as I'm checking if it exists it works.
Now I am trying to filter with a collection filter after searching for all the contacts related to the account but I don't know how to continue. Should I use a collection filter for each of the cases (Contact with values A,B,C, Contact with values, A,C, contact with values B,C), and check that the collections isn't null in a decision element?

Thanks.

Hi, thanks for your question. Just to be clear, why filtering are you attempting currently? From what you have posted so far, it's a bit difficult to understand what you have tried so far and what you are expecting.

What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Please [edit] your post to include screenshots and more details about your flow steps.  Also describe the specific relationship that defines your "related contacts".

@DavidCheng I have edited the question with what I have tried. Contacts have a related account, and I have to know that the account has contacts of the three types present in the multipicklist field. A contact can be of the three types at the same time or there can be two or three contacts with different combinations.

Just as I was using the getrecords to filter each case I used the collection filter and it finally worked

Very good, you can post your own Answer and accept it as the solution.
